# DataBase Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

Please, could anyone tell what is wrong with my sql request?

This is a result:

Database error: Invalid SQL:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT i.item_id) 
FROM
  (
    (
      va_items i 
      INNER JOIN va_items_categories ic 
        ON i.item_id = ic.item_id
    ) 
    INNER JOIN va_categories c 
      ON c.category_id = ic.category_id
  ) 
WHERE i.is_showing = 1 
  AND i.is_approved = 1 
  AND (
    (
      i.hide_out_of_stock = 1 
      AND i.stock_level > 0
    ) 
    OR i.hide_out_of_stock = 0 
    OR i.hide_out_of_stock IS NULL
  ) 
  AND (
    i.language_code IS NULL 
    OR i.language_code = '' 
    OR i.language_code = 'en'
  ) 
  AND i.sites_all = 1 
  AND i.guest_access_level & 2 
  AND (
    ic.category_id = 53 
    OR c.category_path LIKE '0,48,53,%'
  ) (i.price > 0 
    AND i.is_sold = 0)
```

This is the error:

> MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '(i.price > 0 AND i.is_sold = 0)' at line 1

A can`t write full request, because there is a huge script, that forms this request with a lot of logic.

Help me, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an operator AND/OR before `(i.price > 0     AND i.is_sold = 0)` try

```
AND (i.price > 0     AND i.is_sold = 0)
```

or

```
OR (i.price > 0     AND i.is_sold = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(ic.category_id = 53 OR c.category_path LIKE '0,48,53,%') (i.price > 0 AND i.is_sold = 0)
```

That's not valid SQL.  You need something between the close and open parentheses, probably an AND.